# There's too many initializers for char'[8]

Tags: c++, arrays

We're instructed to write a program using a two-dimensional array to list down 40 student names and store them in the array of student records.

Here's my code so far

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int
main ()
{
  cout << "\tStudent name";

  char name[5][8] = {
    {"Airah", "Ariya", "Arissa", "Althea", "Annika"},
    {"Alvin", "Adrielle", "Anthony", "Angelo", "Azriel"},
    {"Belle", "Camila", "Clara", "Elize", "Felicity"},
    {"Isabel", "Irish", "Kaila", "Kitchy","Kianna"},
    {"Lucas", "Miracle", "Natalia", "Primo", "Paris"},
    {"Rafael", "Ryan", "Rico", "Sky", "Serafine"},
    {"Samantha", "Scott", "Timothy", "Theo", "Tyron"},
    {"Winter", "Xyler", "Yohan", "Zachary", "Zhea"},

  }
  {
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)

      printf ("", name[i])}
      }
```

Unfortunately, an error is shown afterward stating that:

```
main.cpp:18:3: error: too many initializers for ‘char [8]’
   18 |   }
      |   ^
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: A `char` is a character, not an entire string of characters. So your entire `name` can only store 40 different characters. Maybe you meant to use `const char * name[5][8]` instead.

Comment: `char name[5][8]` -> `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: You should declare your matrix as `static const`, unless you intend to modify it.  This will help your compiler make your code more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong data type for your array elements. You need `char char*` instead of `char`. You are filling the array with string literals, which are `const char[]` arrays that *decay* into `const char*` pointers.

Also, you have the array dimensions backwards.  You are declaring the array as holding 5 elements (of type `char[8]`), but you are trying to fill it with 8 elements (of type `const char*[5]`).

Also, your `printf()` statement is not actually printing anything at all, since it is passing in an empty format string.  You need `"%c"` to print a single `char`, or `"%s"` to print a string.

Also, your loop is wrong for this type of array.  You can't use 1-dimensional indexes to access a 2-dimensional array. You would need 2 loops, one for each dimension.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "\tStudent name";

  const char* name[8][5] = {
    {"Airah", "Ariya", "Arissa", "Althea", "Annika"},
    {"Alvin", "Adrielle", "Anthony", "Angelo", "Azriel"},
    {"Belle", "Camila", "Clara", "Elize", "Felicity"},
    {"Isabel", "Irish", "Kaila", "Kitchy","Kianna"},
    {"Lucas", "Miracle", "Natalia", "Primo", "Paris"},
    {"Rafael", "Ryan", "Rico", "Sky", "Serafine"},
    {"Samantha", "Scott", "Timothy", "Theo", "Tyron"},
    {"Winter", "Xyler", "Yohan", "Zachary", "Zhea"}
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      printf("%s ", name[i][j]);
      // or: cout << name[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    putchar('\n');
    // or: cout << '\n';
    // or: cout << endl;
  }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/r7UU1C)

If you must use 1-dimensional indexes, then you have to do some extra math to convert them into 2-dimensional indexes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "\tStudent name";

  const char* name[8][5] = {
    {"Airah", "Ariya", "Arissa", "Althea", "Annika"},
    {"Alvin", "Adrielle", "Anthony", "Angelo", "Azriel"},
    {"Belle", "Camila", "Clara", "Elize", "Felicity"},
    {"Isabel", "Irish", "Kaila", "Kitchy","Kianna"},
    {"Lucas", "Miracle", "Natalia", "Primo", "Paris"},
    {"Rafael", "Ryan", "Rico", "Sky", "Serafine"},
    {"Samantha", "Scott", "Timothy", "Theo", "Tyron"},
    {"Winter", "Xyler", "Yohan", "Zachary", "Zhea"}
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    printf("%s ", name[i / 5][i % 5]);
    // or: cout << name[i / 5][i % 5] << ' ';
    if (((i+1) % 5) == 0) {
      putchar('\n');
      // or: cout << '\n';
      // or: cout << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/W6yDgo)